# Is there a way to automatically assign the data by the schedule date or time in laravel, flutter or dart?

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart

Let say I want to post a new data through api. For eg, I am assigning "Milo" as a name on October 10.

```
{
  "name": "Milo",
  "time": 3
}
```

Then 3 days later, on October 13, I want "Cola" to be the name automatically, not "Milo". I don't want to assign it manually. I want to automate it.

Is there a way to do it in laravel, flutter or dart?

Edited...

I've found a way using laravel task scheduling. I don't know that'll work or not in production. Please enlighten me.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
       $schedule->call(function () {
        foreach (Ad::all() as $ad) {
            if (Carbon::now('Asia/Yangon')->format("Y-m-d") == 
       $ad->expire) {
                $ad->serial = 0;
                $ad->name = "null";
                $ad->site = "null";
                $ad->expire = "expired";
                $result = $ad->save();
                if ($result) {
                    return ["killed this one" => $ad];
                } else {
                    return ["error"];
                }
                }
            }
        })->everyMinute();
   }
```

I've seen a post which says "to test it run"

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

I test it successfully but it keeps saying

and "If it works add

```
***** php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

to your cron."

I don't know what cron means. Please enlighten me. I want to make sure the schedule code works in production. I am using windows os.

Comment: Does the API support giving a date for your change or do you have an option to change the API or are you looking to automate the API call at a future date?

Comment: I am looking to automate the api call. I need to edit the question. What I wanna ask is. I'll provide the name and time. "name": "Milo", "time": 7. Then, it'll automatically change the name from "Milo" to "Cola" after 7 days.

Answer (score 3):

you can use timer in initState

```
var data = { name: "alex", time: 3 };

    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(days: data['time']), (Timer timer) async {
        setState(() {
          name = "something"
        });
    });
```

it will execute after 7 days

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've added the additional info to the question. Could you please answer that also?

Comment: ...and you expect the user to keep your app open and in the foreground for the next 7 days?

Comment: It's ok even if one user is opening my app. Thank you for your answer. If there's laravel way please let me know. That way I won't be needing to rely on users opening the app.

Answer (score 1):

use Laravel [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling):

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        // change "Milo" to "Cola" here

    })->daily();
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you I know what scheduling means and edited the question above. Please kindly check the question again.

Comment: Just run that artisan command in production, for more information about cron job please see [Link](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/schedule-cron-jobs-in-php)